# How to get 3 Users on one ROW using SQL ? (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two arrays like this,

First Table (infos):

```
------------------------------
| ID | User1 | User2 | User3 |
------------------------------
| 1  |   20  |   30  |  12   |
------------------------------
```

Second Table (Users):

```
---------------------
| ID | Name | Email |
---------------------
| 12 | Test | Test@ |
---------------------
| 20 | Bla  | Test@ |
---------------------
| 30 | Bate | Test@ |
---------------------
```

I want to get the information of users on one row from the `IDs` on the first table.

I try by getting The row from the first table and fetching on users, but I want to optimize the function with just one Query.

```
SELECT * FROM infos;

SELECT * FROM Infos i,Users u WHERE u.ID = u.User1 (or 2 ...)
```

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use joining the table users 3 times, one for each userid you want show the related name (or other values):

```
select a.id
  , a.user1
  , b.Name as user1name
  , a.user2
  , c.name as user2name
  , a.user3
  , d.name as user3name
from infos a 
inner join   Users b on a.user1 = b.id 
inner join   Users c on a.user1 = c.id 
inner join   Users d on a.user1 = d.id
```

And just as suggested, you should not use old implicit join syntax based on comma-separated table names and where clause, you should use (since 1992) explicit joins. This syntax performs the same query, but is more clear.

Comment: Won't join be a bit heavy?

Comment: @arc  what do you  mean ..???  if you don't join a table how do you think  of retriving the value  form a related  table  ..  ..  ??   .. anyway performance issue can be easy resolved  with a correct indexing ..

Comment: As for the performance stand point, I just thought that parsing the table once will also be a good idea. Yes, you are right, also indexing is a good idea.

Comment: @arc  how you can parsing the table  once  .. and retrive the name for the the  3 different  r column  user1, user2, user3  ..?? .. if you are able to show me the code i'm curious please ..

Answer (score -1):

This is a design error. Use a N:N relation (an additional table) to allow any number of users for the first table. With the relation, other queries will be easier.

A relation table looks like this:

```
create table relation
(
  table1_id int unsigned not NULL,
  table2_id int unsigned not NULL,
  primary key(table1_id,table2_id)
);
```

A typical query (and I dislike `a.*` generally):

```
 select a.*, b.* 
 from table1 a, table2 b, relation r
 where r.table1_id  = a.id
  &&   r.table2_id  = b.id
```